# Eclipse is not showing warnings or errors when a Java source file is opened that is not part of a project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java source file, and in Eclipse I click `File` -> `Open File` and select my file.

The file opens fine in Eclipse and is syntax highlighted, but when I remove a semi colon or try to use a variable before declaring it, Eclipse does not show me any errors etc

Is this possible? Without having to create a project

Comment: Using an other IDE, but one cannot "compile" a non-project java file not knowing its class path or java version. Also one could have set the IDE to use the maven compiler or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the project nature "Java" enabled if you want your file to be treated as Java code. You can create a new "Java project" and drop your file into the src folder. If you have already a simple project try to convert it to a faceted project using the properties dialog and enable facet Java.

Look in the .project file, with the navigator view or directly on disk, and check org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature is present.